# How to make the Camera of UDK (Unreal Developement Kit) Move alone side scrolling?

Tags: unreal-development-kit

I am on a project for a space side scrolling game and I am trying to make the camera of the engine act like an old space shooter game(move alone and when the player pawn stays idle move it alone at its edge), I tried to find tutorials for a spaceship controller but I only found camera options for land units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this would be to overwrite the default Unreal camera and program your own. Here is a quick guide on how to accomplish this. It's quite easy, really.

The first step is to create your custom Camera class. 
Here:

```
class MyCustomCamera extends Camera;

//Camera variables
var Vector mCameraPosition;
var Rotator mCameraOrientation;
var float mCustomFOV;

/**Init function of the camera
*/ 
function InitializeFor(PlayerController PC)
{
      Super.InitializeFor(PC);
      mCameraPosition = Vect(0,0,0);
      //Etc...
}

/**Update function of the camera
*/
function UpdateViewTarget(out TViewTarget OutVT, float DeltaTime)
{
    //This is the meat of the code, here you can set the camera position at each 
    //frame, it's orientation and FOV if need be (or anything else really)

    OutVT.POV.Location = mCameraPosition;
    OutVT.POV.Rotation = mCameraOrientation;
    OutVT.POV.FOV = mCustomFOV;
}
```

The next and last step is to set your new custom camera to be the default one. To do so, in your PlayerController class you add this is the defaultproperties block:

```
CameraClass=class'MyCustomCamera'
```

Now for your specific need of a "scrolling" camera, you could do something as simple as this in your update function :

```
/**Update function of the camera
*/
function UpdateViewTarget(out TViewTarget OutVT, float DeltaTime)
{
    //This is the meat of the code, here you can set the camera position at each 
    //frame, it's orientation and FOV if need be (or anything else really)

    //This will make your camera move on the X axis at speed 50 units per second.
    mCameraPosition += Vect(50*DeltaTime,0,0);

    OutVT.POV.Location = mCameraPosition;
    OutVT.POV.Rotation = mCameraOrientation;
    OutVT.POV.FOV = mCustomFOV;
}
```

Hope this gets you started!